# Drawer item list height in nexus 5

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, nexus-5

The first two items of navigation drawer list items are not properly set in only Nexus S devices. The alignment is working fine all other devices. I dont know why it comes only in this device. Anyone have idea about this.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp" 
android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" /> 



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your drawer_list_item.xml

Comment: Post code that you are using for the drawer.

Comment: I have edited my post with drawer_list_item.xml

Comment: Use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` on your `TextView`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Its working :) @ Muhammad Babar